# How do we calculate the filters in Mel-Frequency Cepstrum Coefficients Algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, voice, frequency

After calculating the FFT and with the frequency we need to do something like this:
http://instruct1.cit.cornell.edu/courses/ece576/FinalProjects/f2008/pae26_jsc59/pae26_jsc59/images/melfilt.png

We filter the frequency spectrum with those triangles.
I saw that we can use distint ways to calculcate the triangles.
I will make the size of the triangles equal till 1kz and after that obtained with log function.

What should we do now? With the frequency spectrum and the triangles defined..
- We should filter the frequency (frequencies limited to the triangles, if goes higher only counts till the triangle limit) and calculate the value of each triangle (and after that continue the algorithm).

But when does the mel conversation happens?
m = 2595 log (f/700 + 1)
When do we pass from frequency to mel..

Can someone guide me in the right direction plz :d

Answer (score 0):

Homework?

Try to map the frequencies to mels in intervals given by triangle overlapping function. You could assume for each interval the mel function is linear. Caculate the power at a given mel frequency with the weights given by the triangle overlapping function.